# How to automatically save a generated QRcode in a specific folder?

Tags: javascript, qr-code

The code below creates a QRcode image in the div.
I would like to save the image created in that div automatically.
I don't need the image to be loaded on the page. Just create and save it in a folder.

```js
(function createQrCode() {
  var qrcode = new
  QRCode("qrcode", {
    text: 'teste',
    width: 256,
    height: 256,
    colorDark: "black",
    colorLight: "white",
    correctLevel: QRCode.CorrectLevel.H
  });
})();
```

```html
<div id="qrcode"></div>
```

Comment: You can start a download but where it ends up is always chosen by the user.

Comment: I get it. But wouldn't it be possible to take the image of the QRcode generated in the div and save it automatically as soon as the page loads?

Comment: "Save it automatically" as in "download"? If no: what exactly do you mean by that? If yes: see my first comment.

Comment: First, thanks for trying to help.

It is not like a download.

I would like to generate and store the image in my folder on the server.

I can generate the QRcode, but I cannot create a script that stores this image automatically.

Sorry, my English is not very good! I've been trying for days, I don't know what else to do.

Comment: Ah, storing it on the server...! That's a very different story. You can either upload it using [`fetch()`](https://www.google.com/search?q=fetch+upload+image) or use a server-side solution in the first place (i.e. generate the QR code on the server using PHP or what have you).